# Rest Versioning for complex JSON

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST API that returns a complex JSON output with multiple combinations of List and Map. 
For the sake of example let's say my Output looks like something

```
    {
    "var1" : 1,
      "var2" : [
          "var2_1" : {
              "var2_1_1" : 10;
              "var2_1_2" : [
                  var2_1_2_1 : 199,
               ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

Here var2, var2_1 and var2_1_2 are the classes. Now suppose my current data type of var2_1_2_1 is Integer and for my next version I want to change it to String. If I am going with my current approach like creating a different class for each collection type variable, I would have to create a new class for var2, var2_1 and var_2_1 that will support my new version response.

With this approach there will be too many classes to maintain(different different classes for each version). I want to keep the classes for latest version only and I will write convertors that will take the input and will make the payload backward compatible(in this case it will parse the var2_1_2_1 from String to Integer).

One approach I can think of it to get the response as String and parse the response with JSONObject, do the conversion and return the String response to user.

Is there any other/better way to fulfill this case ?
My concern here is:
1- I don't want to create many new classes.
2- I want to make conversion from newer version to older version as efficient as possible.

Comment: You could try making var2,var2_1 and var_2_1 generic

Comment: But there is also one case possible like in my next version I want to change any variable from collection type to a single value variable. Like today I am giving all the fare from DestA to DestB in a list but in next version I want to give only the lowest fare.

Comment: You could either insert only one value in the list(kinda meh), or you could have multiple fields and check if they are used( != null) or not, you can manage this in multiple ways, just pick the one that suits you the most